# Существуют ли для MacOS библиотеки похожие на DevExpress для .Net?

Tags: objective-c, swift, macos, devexpress

Интересует прежде всего удобная работа с таблицами, включающая в себя встроенную сортировку, группировку, фильтрации, суммирование и экспорт данных. Хотя бы часть функций.

Вот как выглядит компонент таблица от DevExpress:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так выглядит встроенный редактор DevExpress:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не лишними были бы и другие компоненты, например такие как Reporting, Rich Text, XtraEditors.

В .NET благодаря DevExpress задача написания бизнес-приложений сильно упрощалась. Но под MacOS не знаю что использовать.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что оффтопик, вопрос с просьбой помочь найти библиотеки

Comment: @MaxMikheyenko Судя по тому что мне так никто и не ответил, похоже такой библиотеки не существует (что более чем странно). Так что я не возражаю.

Comment: Можно Visual Studio поставить и юзать ее стандартную тулу для работы с таблицами из коробки прям